# Expression in polar coordinates for a homogeneous smooth function of degree $k$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Assume $u$ is a homogeneous smooth function of degree $k$  in $\mathbb{R} ^n \setminus \{0\}$. I think it is true that if I express the function in polar coordinates then it is of the form $r^k g(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the unit sphere. This is because functions $f(r) g(\omega)$ are dense in the smooth ones. Is the same true if $u$ is in $L^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $r=|x|$ and $\omega=\frac{x}{|x|}\in S^{n-1}$. Then

$$u(x) = u\left(|x|\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}\right)=u(r\omega) = r^k u(\omega)$$

As you can see, no assumptions on $u$ are required. This is valid for *every* function $u:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ homogenous of degree $k$.